# How to visualize data in R with different starting values? (i.e. standardizing so that every data starts from zero)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wrapped my head around this question. The chart should look similar like this:

[image]

So I am basically trying to plot returns but "standardizing" them before. Is there any quick way to do this? I thought about dividing each row entry by the value of the first row respectively, e.g. if stock starts trading at 200, data point 1 will be 200/200=1, datapoint 2 say 210/200= 1.05 etc. - I could then also multiply that value by 100 so I would start the first one with 100, second 105 etc.

Does this make sense or is there a smarter way to do this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may want `seq_along()`. I don't have your data, so here is an example with some dummy data:

```
set.seed(12345)
df <- data.frame(company = c(rep("A", 100), rep("B", 100), rep("C",100), rep("D",100)),
       value = c(rnorm(100, 150, 25), rnorm(100, 250, 25), rnorm(100, 50, 25), rnorm(100, 300, 25)),
       time = c(151:250, 100:199, 200:299, 251:350))
```

Add a new column in your data after grouping by the group/color variable. Use `seq_along()` to populate that column with a sequence of integers starting at 1 for each set. If you need to, transform that new column to whatever scale you need. Note, this only works if your horizontal axis data is evenly spaced. If the intervals are not the same, this will cause trouble.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  group_by(company) %>%
  mutate(time2 = seq_along(time)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time2, y = value, color = company)) +
  geom_line(size = 2) +
  xlab("relative time")
```

[image]

If your data is unevenly spaced, consider transforming to subtract each value per group by the minimum per group. This has the bonus of preserving the interval widths. If you divide by the minimum value, the time intervals will be compressed differently in each group. Again, you could manipulate the new variable in other ways, like adding 100 so that all values start at 100.

```
df %>%
  group_by(company) %>%
  mutate(time2 = time - min(time)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time2, y = value, color = company)) +
  geom_line(size = 2) +
  xlab("relative time")
```

[image]

Comment: That is interesting I will look into this with more detail tomorrow morning since I did not comprehend it fully. I've posted my "work around" solution further below. Do you think that one is viable?

Answer (score 1):

To come back to the solution I've proposed before, I've prepared following dataset:

```
close <- aapl %>% 
select(AAPL.Close) #selecting only the closing prices for apple
```

The first closing price for apple is 32.1875 - for me to make it comparable with another firm independent of the share price I want to "standardize this value". Thus I will divide each row in the dataset by 32.1875 and multiply the solution by 100. This will lead to a new row, which I call relative, that begins with 100 (the base value).

```
close$Relative <- (close$AAPL.Close/32.1875)*100
```

Now I do the same with AMZN, I spare you guys the code the concept is the same. When done I bind both data.frames together:

```
close <- cbind(close,amzn)
```

And plot the data:

```
ggplot(close, aes(x=close$dates))+
geom_line(aes(y=Relative), color="Red")+
geom_line(aes(y=Relative1), color="Blue")
```

[image]